# BorderLayout has large gap in the center

Tags: java, applet, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I am writing a program that is meant to use a BorderLayout with two button on the West and East side of the window. Somehow, there is a large gap in the center. Is there any way that I can eliminate this gap and have the two buttons be tangent with each other? Below I have attached my code. Any help is appreciated :).

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HON extends Applet {

Button p1;
Button p2;
BorderLayout layout;

public void init() {
    layout = new BorderLayout();
    setLayout(layout);

    p1 = new Button("text");
    p2 = new Button("text");

    add(p1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.EAST);

}

public void stop() {

}}
```

Comment: `extends Applet` why, oh why, oh way  - The Java Plugin is deprecated, Applets are deprecated, browsers either non longer support the plugin or actively disable it - time to move on

Comment: Also, AWT based UI's were effectively left behind with the release of Swing in 2000 

Comment: `BorderLayout` works by only give the `EAST` and `WEST` components enough space to honour their preferred width.  The rest of the space is given to the `CENTRE`, there's no real way to change this.  A better solution might be to use something like `GridBagLayout` which will give you more control over the layout

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't know that Applets have been deprecated. Is there an alternative for me to embed my Java program into a website? Thanks you the response btw :)

Comment: HTML5 - most browsers are now moving away from "plugins"

Comment: *"Is there an alternative for me to embed my Java program into a website?"* No! And that's a good thing, given Sun / Oracle were constantly f**king up the security of the end user (to the extent that they might fix a security issue in one Java version, then reintroduce it into the next!). Much the same is true of other plug-ins, as alluded to by @MadProgrammer. If you remove the 'Java' part though, I'd recommend HTML forms for the GUI controls, JavaScript for the logic, and the HTML 5 `canvas` for custom rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderLayout` is doing exactly what the name implies - putting stuff on the border. This is the reason for the gap in the center. If you want to have something that has 2 buttons side by side, I would recommend the `GridLayout` for its simplicity. Code would go something like this:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1,2); // Or (2,1), depending on how you want orientation
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.setLayout(layout);
pane.add(leftButton); // Where leftButton is the JButton (or other swing component) on the left
pane.add(rightButton); // Same goes for the right JButton
// Then add your JPanel to the Frame and all that jazz below.
```

This should do what you want if I understand your question correctly. Notice also that I am using Swing components because they are still maintained by Java. Leave a comment/question if you need any other help with this.

**EDIT:** Notice in the comments that MadProgrammer suggested using the `GridBagLayout`. This is more powerful/versatile than plain vanilla `GridLayout`, but also is a bit harder to learn, so you can sort of take your pick as to which you want to do.

Comment: *"..so you can sort of take your pick as to which you want to do."* Or `FlowLayout`, `BoxLayout` on the line axis.. or perhaps even combining layouts. There are a number of ways to skin this cat, depending on the exact requirements.

Comment: ^ I second this comment. There are many different layouts in Swing, and they all can be useful for different scenarios, so if one doesn't suit your needs, there is probably a different that will.